# How to attach a sprite to a TMXTiledMap at a particular coordinate, in AndEngine?

Tags: andengine, tilemap, grid

I am trying to add a sprite at a "grid" location on the tiled map. The TMX tiled Map is like a grid, and you can access the size of the grid by calling `mTMXtiledMap.getTileRows()` and `mTMXtiledMap.getTileColumns()`.

I want to add an object at grid location, say (2, 5). My tileMap is of size (10,10).

How can I do that? There is no function like `mTMXTiledMap.addChild(int x, int y, Entity mEntity)`.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Are you using "TileD" the map editor? If so then you should add an objects layer and add an object at the grid you want. Once you have done that you can use functions like 'getObject()' to return the position of the object. And then you can add whatever entity you like at the coordinates :)

Comment: Indeed I am using TileD as Map Editor. Adding an objects layer seems to be a good idea. You actually mean adding an object layer within TileD, right? And not something like tmx.addChild(objectLayer). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I mean adding an objects layer in tiled

Answer (score 0):

Just cheat:

Make a method that converts grid coordinates to scene coordinates and then place the sprite at the scene coordinates.  *I.e.*, just multiply the column by the tile width and the row by the tile height.  Boom, you're done.

Sidenote: I'm assuming you want to add the sprite dynamically, as opposed to just changing the map, but yes, if you always want that sprite there, you should just add it to the map using Tiled as [Savlon suggested](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50674/how-to-attach-a-sprite-to-a-tmxtiledmap-at-a-particular-coordinate-in-andengine/50707#comment86435_50674).